# LARAVEL Validação Method PUT

Tags: laravel

Bom Dia, Galera.
sou novato no laravel, procurei sobre o assunto mas nada pode me ajudar(ou que eu tenha entendido), por isso , quem puder me dar uma força ae agradeço.

LARAVEL 5.8 <<<<

Tenho um formulário que direciona p/ controlador

```
<form role="form" method="POST" action="{{route('pedidos.update',$edit->id)}}">
   @method('PUT')                   
   @csrf
```

e no controller:

```
 $rules=$request->validate([
            'nome'=>'required|min:3|max:191',
            'cpf'=>'required|max:11|unique:pedido_seja_socio,cpf,'.$request->id,
        ]);
 if ($rules->fails()){
        redirect(route('verifica.do'))->withErrors($rules)->withInput();
 }
```

e retorna o seguinte erro:

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.
```

se eu comentar (/**/) o treço de código da validação, permite a atualização registros.

Comment: Posta por favor o arquivo route.php com a descrição das rotas para este controller. Acredito que seja a falta da definição de rota para a tela onde o form está sendo montado. Se puder também coloca o código que chama esta view com o form.
PS:Não entendi por quê negativaram tua pergunta.

Comment: era exatamente isso @AdemirMazerJr-Nuno, estava direcionando p/ rota erra, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Você deve estar com problema nas rotas e talvez no formulário. Verifique seu arquivo de rotas para ter certeza que a rota "pedidos.update" está com PUT e tente fazer o formulário desta forma:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => '/', 'method' => 'PUT', 'class'=>'col-md-12')) }}
.... seu código
{{ Form::close() }}
```